# TitledPane loop only last one has content

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml, gridpane

I am building my `fxml` programmatically.

Now I'm adding a titledpanes to my accordion and in those titledpane I have `setContent` to a gridpane that is defined in the loop.

The result screen shows all titledpanes i've added. It shows the title of the titledpanes I set. But it only shows the content of the last titledpane I added.

I don't understand why, as the reference to the titledpane still exists in the arraylist I made and in my understanding the content(Node) I have set is saved there. And it looks like the row and columnconstraints are working for all instances, which I think means that the grid has been found for every TitledPane but every but the last one is without content.

```
Public class FXMLController Implements Initializable {

@FXML private VBox vboxDrills;

//NonFXML
private ArrayList<TitledPane> lsttpDrillList;
private Accordion accDrill;



public void initLayout(ArrayList<Drill> drills){
    accDrill = new Accordion();
    lsttpDrillList = new ArrayList<>();
    TitledPane tpDrill; //AP = AccordionPane
    GridPane gpTopDrill;
    Accordion accDrillStep;
    GridPane gpBottomDrill;

    //gpTopDrill
    ColumnConstraints cc1gpTopDrill = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc1gpTopDrill.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
        cc1gpTopDrill.setMaxWidth(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        cc1gpTopDrill.setMinWidth(10.0);
        cc1gpTopDrill.setPrefWidth(200.0);
    ColumnConstraints cc2gpTopDrill = new ColumnConstraints();
        cc2gpTopDrill.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
        cc2gpTopDrill.setMaxWidth(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        cc2gpTopDrill.setMinWidth(10.0);
        cc2gpTopDrill.setPrefWidth(400.0);
    RowConstraints rc1gpTopDrill = new RowConstraints();
        rc1gpTopDrill.setMaxHeight(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        rc1gpTopDrill.setMinHeight(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        rc1gpTopDrill.setPrefHeight(35.0);
        rc1gpTopDrill.setVgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
    Label lblDrillID = new Label();
        lblDrillID.minHeight(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        lblDrillID.minWidth(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        lblDrillID.setText("Drill ID:");
    Label lblActualID = new Label();
        lblActualID.minHeight(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        lblActualID.minWidth(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
    Label lblDrillTitle = new Label();        
        lblDrillTitle.setText("Drill Title:");
    TextField txtDrillTitleEdit = new TextField();
    //end gpTopDrill


    for(int i=0; i<drills.size(); i++){
        //new instance and title
        Drill drill = drills.get(i);
        tpDrill = new TitledPane();
        if(!drill.getTitle().isEmpty()){
            tpDrill.setText(drill.getTitle());
        }else{
            tpDrill.setText("Drill" + drill.getID());
        }
        tpDrill.setId("drillPane" + (i));

        //gpTopDrill
        lblActualID.setText(Integer.toString(drill.getID()));
        txtDrillTitleEdit.setId("drillTitleEdit" + (i));
        txtDrillTitleEdit.setText(drill.getTitle());

        GridPane.setConstraints(lblDrillID, 0, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblActualID, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblDrillTitle, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(txtDrillTitleEdit, 1, 1);

        gpTopDrill = new GridPane();
        gpTopDrill.getColumnConstraints().addAll(cc1gpTopDrill, cc2gpTopDrill);
        gpTopDrill.getRowConstraints().addAll(rc1gpTopDrill, rc1gpTopDrill);
        gpTopDrill.getChildren().addAll(lblDrillID, lblActualID, lblDrillTitle, txtDrillTitleEdit);
        //end gpTopDrill

        //accDrillStep

        //end accDrillStep

        //gpBottomDrill

        //end gpBottomDrill

        //put VBox in drillpane
        tpDrill.setContent(gpTopDrill);
        lsttpDrillList.add(tpDrill);

    }

    accDrill.getPanes().setAll(lsttpDrillList);
    accDrill.layoutXProperty().set(8.0);
    accDrill.layoutYProperty().set(7.0);
    accDrill.setExpandedPane(lsttpDrillList.get(0));
    vboxDrills.getChildren().add(0, accDrill);
}
...
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmREr.png)

Comment: Surely you want to create a new `TitledPane` on each iteration of the loop, instead of creating just one and re-configuring it on each iteration?

Comment: yes, that is actually what I should have been doing :O. Thanks. But why are they blank then instead of all looking like the third?

Comment: Because you're making the same mistake with the labels; reconfiguring them and adding the same label to all the titled panes. Since controls can only appear once in the same scene graph, you only see them in the last place they were added.